# ¿Hay forma de reconocer el único archivo que hay en una carpeta con php?

Tags: php

Tengo una duda, no sé si sea posible tampoco he encontrado información, pero quiero saber si por ejemplo:

Quiero llamar un archivo por medio de una ruta, pero no me sé el nombre del archivo, pero el nombre de la carpeta sí, y es el único archivo que existe en ella.

¿Hay posibilidad de que lo detecte directamente y de qué manera se puede hacer?

Se los agradezco.

Lo necesito es para llamar un archivo pdf, es mucho más código, pero aquí como tal es dónde pongo la ruta

```
pdfjsLib.getDocument('../documents/REGLAMENTO DE H&SI JOMAR INVERSIONES SAS 2019.pdf').then((pdf) => {
        myState.pdf = pdf;
        render();
    });
```

Comment: La respuesta corta es si, pero... ¿podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar el código que tienes hasta el momento? Más que nada esto es para poder darte una respuesta que pueda servirte sin tener que hacer varios cambios

Comment: Pues la verdad no es como sí lo haya intentado, porque no he encontrado información, así que tendría que modificar lo necesario

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Opción 1:

Para obtener la lista de archivos que se encuentran dentro de un directorio podemos utilizar la función [`scandir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

Si llamamos a la función `scandir` indicando la bandera `SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING` y el directorio tiene exactamente un archivo, entonces, el nombre del archivo será el primer resultado en el arreglo.

#### Ejemplo:

```
$dir = '../documents';
$files = scandir($dir, SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
$filename = $files[0];
// Debes validar que $filename sea distinto de '.' y de '..'
```

---

### Opción 2:

Ya que sabemos que la extensión del archivo es `.pdf`, también podemos utilizar [`glob`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.glob.php)

#### Ejemplo:

```
$files = glob("../documents/*.pdf");
// Validar que $files no este vacio
$filename = $files[0];
```

Comment: Amigo, En js también se puede hacer?

Comment: En un navegador

Comment: `JavaScript` no tiene acceso al `FileSystem` del sistema del usuario y tampoco al del servidor.

Comment: Ah, listo, gracias, voy a aplicarlo y te comento